# Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) returns list of files in same order always?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to return a list of files (paginated response) to the caller because there might be too many files in the directory.
I am wondering if the order is always maintained maybe by name or some date than we are good, otherwise the caller might get the same file multiple times.

Is there a better way or my assumptions are correct ?
I was also wondering if we write the code to manually iterate throught the files and folders and stop collecting if our criteria is met to save memory ?

OS windows and Linux
.Net 6

Currently I am getting the files

IEnumerable files = await Task.Run(() => Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));

and then just taking the batch from this whole list.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable` does not guaranty any order. You can use `IEnumerable.OrderBy` to sort the collection.

```
    IEnumerable<string> files = await Task.Run(() => Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    IOrderedEnumerable<string> orderedFiles = files.OrderBy((file) => file);
```